# Why does this python script work on Ubuntu but not Raspbian?

Tags: python, ubuntu, smtp, beautifulsoup, raspbian

A friend and I created the following script utilizing BeautifulSoup to get the HTML of a job page, then append the job to an array, then a file, then email the job in a human-readable format to ourselves. The script works on Ubuntu, but on my Raspberry Pi, which uses Raspbian, it doesn't work.

The only message I see when running from the terminal is: 'end of file' and 'Start write...' which are lines in the code. There are no error messages when running from the Pi, but nothing gets appended to the array and no emails are sent.

Can someone take a look? Thanks.

```
import urllib2, email, smtplib, os.path
import cPickle as pickle
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

class Job:
    """docstring for Job"""
    def __init__(self, title, date, url):
        self.title = title
        self.date = date
        self.url = "http://www.forensicfocus.com/"+url
    def describJob(self):
        return (self.title +" "+ self.date +" "+ self.url)

def createJobsArray():
    soup = BeautifulSoup(urllib2.urlopen('http://www.forensicfocus.com/jobs').read())
    bigFatString = soup.find_all('a')
    #print(bigFatString) #this gets webpage as html. No issues here
    findAll = soup.find_all("tr", class_="topic")
    jobsArray = []
    for section in findAll:
        title = section.find("a", class_="topictitle").get_text()
        titleEncoded = title.encode('ascii','ignore')
        row = section.find_all("td")
        date = row[3].find("div").get_text()
        url = section.find_all("a")[3].get("href")
        job = Job(titleEncoded, date, url)
        print "printing job"
        print job
        print "printing job"
        jobsArray.append(job)
    return jobsArray


def sendEmail(job):
    senderEmail = "sender@example.com"
    recipients = ["destination@example.com"]
    s = smtplib.SMTP("smtp.gmail.com",587)
    s.ehlo()
    s.starttls() 
    s.ehlo()
    s.login(senderEmail, 'pass_goes_here')
    for job in jobsFilteredByLocation:
        msg = email.message_from_string(job.describJob())
        msg['Subject'] = "New Job Found: " + job.title
        s.sendmail(senderEmail, recipients, msg.as_string())
        print "Sending email..."
    s.quit()

def saveJobsToDisk(jobs):
    with open('hadooken', 'wb') as output:
        print "Start write..."
        for job in jobs:
            print job.title
            pickle.dump(job, output)
        output.close()

def getJobsFromDisk():
    oldJobsArray = []
    with open('hadooken', 'rb') as input:
        while True:
            try:
                job = pickle.load(input)
                print job.title, "was successfully read from file"
                oldJobsArray.append(job)
            except EOFError:
                print "end of file"
                break   
        return oldJobsArray
        input.close()

# SCRIPT STARTS HERE        
with open('hadooken', 'ab') as input:
    input.close()

locationsArray = ["London"]
jobsArray = createJobsArray()

oldJobsArray = getJobsFromDisk()

jobsFilteredByLocation = []

for job in jobsArray:
    for location in locationsArray:

        found = job.title.find(location)

        if found > 0:
            if len(oldJobsArray) > 0:
                if any(oldJob.title == job.title for oldJob in oldJobsArray):
                    print "Job previously found and sent..."
                else:
                    print "adding ", job.title, "to array because it isnt in the old array"
                    jobsFilteredByLocation.append(job)
            else:
                print "adding ", job.title, "to array"
                jobsFilteredByLocation.append(job)

sendEmail(jobsFilteredByLocation)

mergedArray = oldJobsArray + jobsFilteredByLocation

for job in mergedArray:
    print "Job title: ", job.title
saveJobsToDisk(mergedArray)
```

Comment: Add a bunch more print statements to figure out exactly where it starts hanging.

Comment: Unrelated, but closing an open file is unnecessary when using `with`. `with` will implicitly close the file for you.